# Certbot Google-DNS Failing from AWS EC2

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google, certbot

I am trying to retrieve an SSL Cert using Certbot from an Unbuntu 22 instance on AWS and it keeps getting the following error:

```
Simulating a certificate request for studiojb-demo.com and *.studiojb-demo.com
Encountered exception during recovery: socket.timeout: timed out
An unexpected error occurred:
socket.timeout: timed out
```

**Things to note:**

1. I have another instance running on the same AWS subnet which runs fine.
2. I have posted on community.letsencrypt.org and a Certbot engineer informs me it's a network issue to google. Here: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/encountered-exception-during-recovery-socket-timeout-timed-out/196512/8

**My Question[s]:**

Does Google DNS block requests from AWS IPAddress spaces? Possible previous mal attempts?

How would I troubleshoot this?

Thank you,

GES

Comment: Welcome to SF :) Only Google can answer your direct question. If you want some more practical help I suggest you edit your question to add more background about what you're trying to achieve, command line, etc.